# How to select a cell phone (mobile phone) that will have the best camera hardware and software?

Tags: smartphone, cameraphones, mobile, portable, selection

Shortly before the COVID-19 pandemic began, I had the opportunity to attend a few art gallery openings that featured photography.

What surprised me was that some of the photographs were taken using cell phones (aka mobile phones, smartphones, and cameraphones).  What surprised me even more was that some of these photos were enlarged to over 2m wide, and still looked good.

My first quality camera was medium format (followed by large format), so this was a real eye-opening experience for me.

As all photographers know, the foremost challenge to taking a good photograph is actually having a camera with you when you see an opportunity.

Cell phones have given us an easy-to-carry and portable solution to almost always have a camera (and even a short-range flash!) with us.  But finding a cell phone with quality camera hardware and software can be challenging.  Four issues make this especially challenging:

1. Cell phone models are constantly being introduced, making previous comparative reviews less valuable.
2. Cell phone brands and model availability are not consistent around the world.  This is partly because different technologies and frequencies are used in different regions.
3. Cell phone prices vary considerably, and different people have different budgets.  Phone XYZ might technically offer the best combination of hardware and software, but it might be twice the price of a device that is 99% as good.
4. The cameras of many cell phones get great reviews because they generate reasonable quality images if you never enlarge your photographs.  But once you enlarge them to sizes appropriate for hanging in a gallery, quality often (but definitely not always) degrades to unacceptable levels.

Taking the above into consideration, how does a photographer select a cell phone that will have the best camera hardware and software that will meet their desires (those desires, of course, tempered by an understanding of the current limits of technology, manufacturing, and form factor)?

Comment: "...how does a photographer select..." – The same way anyone selects anything else... read reviews, talk to sales people and other users, try it out, flip a coin.

Comment: This question misses the point in many ways.  Yes, cell phone cameras are getting far better because that is one of the things that makes people choose one phone over another.  The question assumes photographers are an amorphous class.  Different photographers want to take different pictures.  Some of those pictures can be taken by a cell phone.  You need to want a lens in the effective focal length range that is available and good light because of the small sensor.  There are great photos available in that space.  There are great photos outside that space.

Comment: Some photographers will want to have a phone that will take the photos they want to take.  Others will ignore the phone camera and use something else.  I am in that group because the pictures I see are with long lenses that phones do not offer.

Comment: Voting on close, as this is very open and opinion based.

Comment: I agree the question appears to make assumptions that wont be valid for many situations.  For example, smartphones typically don't integrate with off-camera lighting and angle of view is limited to what the smartphone offers (and cropping options).  It is a very broad question.

Comment: @TimCampbell Okay, how about I change the question to *how do I*, instead of *how do photographers*?  I was sincerely trying to be helpful to the community by being inclusive, but as they say, "No good deed goes unpunished".

Comment: @TimCampbell You might be surprised with relatively recent developments. Check out the Godox A1 introduced in 2017. Combined with the app (there are both Android and iPhone versions) it allows many smartphones to control and trigger the entire range of the Godox 2.4Ghz line using a smartphone as the camera.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket That would help, but what I think this needs is for you to say what _your_ needs are. Do you care about portrait, landscape, low light, something else? We can probably if we know what goal you're _personally_ trying to achieve, rather than what "photographers" (a very broad category) try to do.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have a leg in each camp.  Right now I'm renting a beast of a 600mm lens for mainly wildlife photography.   Yet I use my phone's camera for easily taking video of the 500 to 1000 birds as the fly overhead.

Comment: I recently saw someone taking bird photos with an add-on lens for a cell phone that was probably 1 inch diameter by 3 or 4 inches long.  I don't know what effective focal length or quality it provided.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Those are great suggestions.  Thank you.  I will edit this question or delete it and post a new question.  It may take me a week or longer to do it, but I've added the task to my list.

Comment: This question deserves an updated answer. Technology has changed a lot in the last year or two. ¶ For instance, some devices now have 8K video recording (32 megapixel images).  Rather than taking individual composed photos, one simply video records a session, selects the best frames (at 60 frames per second there's a lot of choice), crops out the perfect part, and ends up with an image with higher resolution than most DSLRs could produce not long ago. This overkill effectively eliminates the need for framing and timing skills required for great photographs.

Comment: @RayButterworth Thanks Ray. How does the quality of a still taken from video compare to a still taken by itself? About 2 years ago, I was taking close-range (but not macro; my lens was about 20cm away) of an amazing insect. The insect was moving around quite a bit, and the scene was lit by sunlight beaming through the leaves of a nearby tree. I took over 800 stills until I finally got this amazing insect in an interesting position while wonderfully illuminated by a gorgeous beam of light. If I could have simply turned on video and extract a few frames, the process would have been much easier.

Comment: (...continued) I'm not sure if it would have been nearly as satisfying, but wow, it would have been so much easier and faster.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, I've not used it myself, only seen the commercials.   That's why I commented rather than answering. My impression is that you get a very long burst of full 32Mpx images and can select the part of it that you want, as the new normal way of taking photographs. ¶ If you've never seen an 8K TV, next chance you get, do so. They are amazing. In standby mode they can be set to display a still image, making the TV indistinguishable from a framed painting on the wall, with its light intensity automatically adjusting to the ambient light in the room.

Comment: @RayButterworth But then what do I do with all the framed paintings on my wall? ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not an answer, but a long comment.

> How to select a cell phone (mobile phone) that will have the best camera hardware

Read reviews, technical sheets, and choose one based on your needs and budget.

> and software

Read reviews, if it is not installed on the phone I bet you can buy it and install it.

> Cell phone models are constantly being introduced, making previous comparative reviews less valuable.

So, look for some other reviews. Some companies live for this. Some websites review things even before you can get them on a store. Some come to my mind:

[www.dxomark.com](http://www.dxomark.com)

[www.dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com)

---

This is a strong opinion based.

> Cell phone models are constantly being introduced, making previous comparative reviews less valuable.

Thinking like that will paralyze you.

Yes, there will be for sure a better camera or phone somewhere, more modern, and probably will be a time where the phone does not even need you.

Get what you can and enjoy taking photos.

> Cell phone brands and model availability are not consistent around the world.

So? The same, work with what you can have, instead of thinking about you can not.

---

Here is a bit more specific point but also subjective.

> The cameras of many cell phones get great reviews because they generate reasonable quality images

Depends on the reviews. Some of them are very technical for example about sharpness and noise.

> if you never enlarge your photographs.

I really doubt that is a reason for a good or bad review. The review could simply include information about Mpx, and give you a hint on print size.

> But once you enlarge them to sizes appropriate for hanging in a gallery, quality often (but definitely not always) degrades to unacceptable levels.

What is that acceptable size? **What is quality?** Quality "does not degrade" **quality is a process**. Yes, you can put some limits on the technical side, for example, you can simply "exclude" a print of less than 100ppi... does this mean that a photo of 99ppi does not have any artistic merit?

---

Just as an example of printing sizes.

A 12Mpx image, common on some phones and old dslr has 4000 on the long side.

You can safely print it as 100ppi or with a simple 2x resampling to blur a bit the pixels and print it at 200ppi. This will give you a print of 40inches or 1m.

Is it good for a gallery? I'm pretty sure it is.

Some phones even have more than 48Mpx on the sensor. 80 inches or 2m.

Comment: On that last point, I think I would say, if you're looking to enlarge an image for the purpose of hanging it in a gallery, you're probably not going to be looking at a cell phone as the imaging device. At least, I wouldn't be. I would be looking at something with far more flexibility - DSLR or mirrorless, or even medium/large format. And shooting RAW - not trying to extremely upscale a JPEG...

Comment: Again one needs to see reviews. A 12Mpx file could be great, iPhone cameras can take nice images, and Huawei ones have even 50Mpx sensors. That is not to be viewed on the phone.